# Common flags of multiple modes with cmdargs explicit

Tags: haskell, haskell-cmdargs

I'm writing a command line program with **Haskell** and [**cmd-args**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs) with the  [**Explicit**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.14/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Explicit.html) module.

The [**Implicit**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cmdargs-0.10.14/docs/System-Console-CmdArgs-Implicit.html) module provide a default help message with a list of differents modes with the common flags to these modes, like this :

```
diffy [COMMAND] ... [OPTIONS]
  Create and compare differences

Common flags:
  -o --out=FILE     Output file
  -? --help         Display help message
  -V --version     Print version information

diffy create [OPTIONS]
  Create a fingerprint

  -s  --src=DIR  Source directory

diffy diff [OPTIONS] OLDFILE NEWFILE
  Perform a diff
```

**Is it possible to make the same thing with the Explicit module ?**

**Is there a function in cmdargs giving the commons flags of several modes ?**